# Why can't Typescript infer function argument types for optional arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I think it's clearer to try it on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFUTQA8oMUBnRACgDp6BDAJwHMKAuRBsbAbQF0AlIgC8APi48x1YGE75B8xAG8AUIkRM0UEEySyA3KoC+q1aEiwEiWdWZtOajRABGnGXDicwIALYu0JmFxRAA3OFQAGhNhZVNzMGonRFdOVAwsbGoPOGCJOMFo40Ejc3BoeH0wACY7Vg4VdRSXAH53YE9vPwCg0QlwqJiVeNla5NTkdEwYHGyO3L7hwpjSiwrrWQBmOodG5zcaea7-QLywiJQixAAfJeGzLaSmifTp2ZyzgqKSoA):

```
function identity<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T): T {
  return fn;
}

function fn(args: {
  cb: (foo: number) => void,
}) {}

fn({
  cb: identity((foo /* infers number */) => {}),
});

function fn2(args: {
  cb?: (foo: number) => void,
}) {}

fn2({
  cb: identity((foo /* doesn't infer number */) => {}),
});

function fn3(args: {
  cb: (foo: number) => void,
} | {}) {}

fn3({
  cb: identity((foo /* infers number */) => {}),
});
```

For `fn` and `fn3`, TS was able to infer that `foo` is a `number`. However, for `fn2`, TS just typed `foo` as `any`. The typing for `fn2` and `fn3` are functionally the same thing, so I'm wondering why TS couldn't infer the type of `foo`.

The realistic use-case for this is React's `useCallback`, I was trying to infer the argument types for functions that pass through `useCallback`.

Why does TS behave like this? Is there a less hacky solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think the crucial step here is the inference of `identity`s return type:

```
 let result: ((foo: number) => void | undefined) = identity(...);
```

As the return type has a base constraint of `(...args: any[]) => any` this rule of the Typescript specification applies:

> The inferred type argument for each type parameter is the union type of the set of inferences made for that type parameter. However, if the union type does not satisfy the constraint of the type parameter, the inferred type argument is instead the constraint.

> ~ [TypeScript Language Specification (outdated), Contextual Signature Instantiation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification%20-%20ARCHIVED.pdf)

As `undefined` (the optional value) does not satisfy the constraint, the constraint is taken, and T gets inferred as `(...args: any[]) => any`.

By removing the constraint, T [gets inferred correctly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=6&pln=7&pc=29#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFUQHoAqRNADygxQGdEAKAOhYEMAnAc1oC5FWw2ANoBdAJSIAvAD5+gxCSLSGwMH3xj1iAN4AoRInZooIdklUBuXQF9dd0JFgJEqhh2589BiACM+KuDg+MBAAWx80dgkZRAA3OFQAGhsJbVtdVy9EXz5UDCxsBgC4aNk0sWTrMSsM8Gh4czAAJjcuXh19bJ8Afn9gQOCwiKipWXiklJ101RasnOR0TBgcIv6S0amKlJqHeudVAGZWjw7vP0Y1wfDI0riElErEAB9NqfswI7nzvKWV4tvypVqrogA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `fn2` the `cb` arg is `optional`, so `identity` can't infer from that. So you want to explicit tell TS that that arg can be undefined like so:

```
function fn2(args: {
  cb: (foo: number) => void | undefined
}) {}
```

This should do the trick and make the infer work again.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFUTQA8oMUBnRACgDp6BDAJwHMKAuRBsbAbQF0AlIgC8APi48x1YGE75B8xAG8AUIkRM0UEEySyA3KoC%20q1aEiwEiWdWZtOajRABGnGXDicwIALYu0JmFxRAA3OFQAGhNhZVNzMGonRFdOVAwsbGoPOGCJOMFo40Ejc3BoeH0wACY7Vg4VdRS3GmBPbz8AoNEJcNREAB9EcHRgGDA0FCLY%20Nla5NTkdEwYHGy23J6VYunSiwrrWQBmOodG5xacjv9AvLCIqZNB7ZmzY6SmxfSVtZy7gt2QAhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFUTQA8oMUBnRACgDp6BDAJwHMKAuRBsbAbQF0AlIgC8APi48x1YGE75B8xAG8AUIkRM0UEEySyA3KoC%20q1aEiwEiWdWZtOajRABGnGXDicwIALYu0JmFxRAA3OFQAGhNhZVNzMGonRFdOVAwsbGoPOGCJOMFo40Ejc3BoeH0wACY7Vg4VdRS3GmBPbz8AoNEJcNREAB9EcHRgGDA0FCLY%20Nla5NTkdEwYHGy23J6VYunSiwrrWQBmOodG5xacjv9AvLCIqZNB7ZmzY6SmxfSVtZy7gt2QA)

Comment: Doing it like this makes `cb` no longer optional and needs to be supplied as `undefined` Why wouldn't identity be able to infer from an optional parameter?

Comment: I'm not really aware of the why the `identity` right now can't infer from the `optional` value, but thinking at the use case of a `useCallback` it should work correctly since you won't use a `useCallback` without a callback function inside, am I wrong?